# Why use custom layers in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

TF 2.x gives the keras API which makes the process of making neural networks really smooth. Why then should someone still use custom layers? Allow me to illustrate -

Why should I use something like this -

```py
class ResnetIdentityBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
    super(ResnetIdentityBlock, self).__init__(name='')
    filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters

    self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1))
    self.bn2a = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size, padding='same')
    self.bn2b = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.conv2c = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters3, (1, 1))
    self.bn2c = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
    x = self.bn2a(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.conv2b(x)
    x = self.bn2b(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.conv2c(x)
    x = self.bn2c(x, training=training)

    x += input_tensor
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


block = ResnetIdentityBlock(1, [1, 2, 3])
```

instead of something as such -

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2, 2), input_shape=(64, 64, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Clearly the second code block is much more readable. What's the use of the style of coding (a nn) illustrated in the first code snippet?

EDIT: I know the code snippets do not do the same thing but my concern is with usage of OOP instead of just plainly defining (like in the second block).

Comment: You're missing the point by glossing over the fact that the first snippet does something completely different. I dare you to implement a residual network in Keras using only `Sequential` and no custom layers...

Comment: see I’m new DL/AI. So for me it’s important to know the difference.

Comment: Ok so...after some research. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If I wanna make a more complicated neural network and/or reuse them its always beneficial to go for first route. Else just keep it simple and use the second way right?

Answer (score 1):

The `Sequential` abstraction sure is useful, but it limits your vocabulary with respect to **which** operations you can use and **how**; i.e. you are constrained to sequential architectures of the form f<sub>1</sub>(f<sub>2</sub>(...f<sub>n</sub>(x))..), where each one of f<sub>i</sub> must be a distinct instance of a finite number of pre-implemented classes.

For instance, consider a weight-tied architecture of the same convolution being applied multiple times at various stages of the pipeline, or (like in the example you posted), a residual connection that "skips" some layers<sup>1</sup>.

So, `Sequential` definitely is good enough to organize and run simple architectures, but for anything more complicated than that it's guaranteed to give you more of a headache in the long run.

---

<sup>1</sup>: *I haven't personally used Keras in a while -- it might be the case that there are Layer classes that allow one to implement residual connections or weight sharing; this was just meant to illustrate my point.*

Comment: So essentially, if I wanna make a more complicated neural network and/or reuse them its always beneficial to go for first route. Else just keep it simple and use the second way right?

Comment: Also just a side Q. Can you tell me what the syntax would look like in ```call()``` if I had say 100 layers? I mean I wont be copy-pasting the first layer a 100 times and then change a few things (like they've done in the call method). I think it'll be some sort of a for loop but I want to know exactly